# FOSUserBundle - Overriding Controller

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, overriding

I am having a little (frustrating) issues trying to override the ResettingController of FOSUserBundle.

I have followed the docs to the letter*. I am having no joy overriding the controller or the event subscribe for onResettingPasswordSucess...

Here is my controller:

namespace AppBundle\Controller\Frontend;

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ResettingController as BaseResettingController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class ResettingController extends BaseResettingController
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function requestAction()
    {
        return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Resetting:request.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function sendEmailAction(Request $request)
    {
        $username = $request->request->get('username');

        /** @var $user UserInterface */
        $user = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByUsernameOrEmail($username);

        if (null === $user) {
            return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Resetting:request.html.twig', array(
                'invalid_username' => $username
            ));
        }

        if ($user->isPasswordRequestNonExpired($this->container->getParameter('fos_user.resetting.token_ttl'))) {
            return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Resetting:passwordAlreadyRequested.html.twig');
        }

        if (null === $user->getConfirmationToken()) {
            /** @var $tokenGenerator \FOS\UserBundle\Util\TokenGeneratorInterface */
            $tokenGenerator = $this->get('fos_user.util.token_generator');
            $user->setConfirmationToken($tokenGenerator->generateToken());
        }

        $this->get('fos_user.mailer')->sendResettingEmailMessage($user);
        $user->setPasswordRequestedAt(new \DateTime());
        $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($user);

        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login',
            array('email' => $this->getObfuscatedEmail($user))
        ));
    }
}
```

My AppBundle has this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

Even PhpStorm tell me...
[image]

However the parent method is always being called?

All I want is when user submits the password reset form it redirects them to the login page with a flash message.

Can you spot anything?

Kindest Regards
Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All I want is when user submits the password reset form it redirects them to the login page with a flash message

Use Events, it's right way for you issue. [Hooking into the controllers](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md)

Comment: I tried that also and nothing. I'll post event tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Did you by any chance forget to flush your cache ?

PS : What color scheme are you using ? it's pretty nice

Comment: I did, and kept debugging the event.subscribe tags and my event was there but it would always default to FOS's event.

Thanks it's SpacePeacock :) https://github.com/ShawnMcCool/PHPStorm-SpacePeacock

Comment: Thanks. BTW in your screenshot you show that the requestAction is overwritten, but don't you want the sendMailAction to be ? (it's a bit confusing)